# Image segmentation with cityscapes dataset

Tags: machine-learning, image-segmentation

I am a beginner in image segmentation and am trying to use the code:

```
from dilatednet import DilatedNet
from multiclassunet import Unet
```

but get the error:

```
No module named 'dilatednet'
No module named 'multiclassunet'
```

I am using [this GitHub file](https://github.com/srihari-humbarwadi/cityscapes-segmentation-with-Unet/blob/master/batch_training.py).  Can anyone help?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? It is not clear from the question.

Comment: It might be more helpful for you to go through some of [the public notebooks on this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/cityscapes-image-pairs/code).

Comment: Have you included both the `dilatednet.py` and `multiclassunet.py` files from the repository in the same folder? The script you've linked is trying to import classes from those two files, and if you don't have those files the imports will file.